# Program for communicating with windows named pipes

Tags: windows, cygwin, named-pipes, socat

I am relatively new to named pipes in windows.

I require a windows tool similar to linux's *socat* for communicating via named pipes. Can Cygwin's socat access windows named pipes? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself quickly enough.

Used putty and the serial as the connection type. Typed the full pipe name in the serial line box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from smichak you can actually use the Putty's plink with socat to get a cygwin pipe:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/openssh-ssh-agent,umask=066,fork EXEC:"PLINK.EXE -serial //./pipe/openssh-ssh-agent",pipes
```

Comment: Does this work with agent fowarding?  I tried it in msys2 and my local ssh agent properly connected to Windows ssh-agent service, but it failed to connect from a remote server that had the agent forwarded to it.

Comment: @ttk this is most likely caused by the outdated ssh-agent version in windows. Using the latest beta from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH fixed it for me